# SVN - Why did my directory double in size after checking out a working copy?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Using Tortoise SVN, I wanted to have an incremental backup of my Unreal project directory so I created a repository and exported my project folder which is 165GB total size. I then deleted the original directory after the successful commit and checked out the working copy using SVN Update. Now the project folder is 331GB! It's got all of the regular files, but also the .svn folder is another 165GB. How the heck do I stop this from happening? I don't have enough HD space.

Comment: This is the way Subversion works. Why do you have 165GB! in version control?

Comment: well, it's just a local backup of my project. Basically, I'm using it like a time machine archive. I guess I should probably switch to Macrium Reflect then.

Comment: 1. backup your repository, not your working copy. 2. use `svn export`.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is already stored in your Subversion repository. You need to **backup the repository**, not your local working copy. You can backup your working copy, but backing up your repository is more important since it has your revision history. Note that

1. you could use `svn export` instead of `svn checkout` to get the latest snapshot of your repository and its size will be 165GB.
2. pristineless Subversion working copies is a work-in-progress and maybe will be released in one of the next major updates of Apache Subversion. See [SVN-525: Allow working copies without .svn/pristine/ cache (a.k.a. "text-base/" files)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SVN-525).

Comment: What I'm saying is, after importing my files and then downloading them to the working directory, the working directory is twice the size as the imported directory. That seems unnecessary to me since the files all were sent over to the repository and stored there.